# Mixed Marriage Question

Tags: family-members, orthodox, intermarriage

So here’s my problem.  I’m Baal Teshuva (MO) and my partner is not Jewish.  I know, I know! It’s complicated. She has no interest in converting, but totally supports me.  As for me, I’m just trying to find my place and be true to myself.  It is what it is.  But I am looking for guidance - for both of us.  Does anyone have any recommendations for me - how to find my way Jewishly while maintaining my family - and for her - to help her understand what I am doing (even I don’t understand!)

Any help is appreciated - and - I’m hoping, no judgement.

Thanks!

Comment: When I started practicing Judaism after being raised without, my Orthodox rabbi took me aside and wanted to make sure that nothing I learned from him would dissolve the family with children that my gentile wife and I had.  We are still married over a decade later and she still does not want to convert. Sometimes for a tinok shenishba life doesn't follow the ideal rules.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Christopher and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.